# Searching for OPEN client case and automatically displaying CLOSED cases if OPEN CASE not found

Tags: delphi, null

SQL NEWBIE on the hunt for a solution.
We have a database of clients and one of the fields is called CLOSED.  If it contains a value it has been closed and empty otherwise.  CLOSED cases will not show up during a search unless I run a separate query to display them. So when I run the search and nothing shows up I then select another button on my DELPHI app to display CLOSED cases. I want a one button option to be able to search for a case and if nothing found automagically continue or repeat the search to display the CLOSED cases.  Not sure what the SQL query is for doing this.  But I believe I'm in the right place to get an answer......Thanks in advance people....

Comment: Actually you should  edit your question and add `SQL` tag to your question as getting desired results only requires you to use proper SQL query. And you can remove both `Delphi` and `Null` tags since only your third scenario (automatically executing second query when first returns no results) would be dependent of Delphi code. And to get answer for that you should also add information of which database components are you using.

Comment: What is your `[sql]` or `[delphi]` question?

Comment: Don't worry too much about the tags on your q for now.  The two most important things for getting effective help are to edit your q  to :  a) say what database back-end you are using (e.g. MS Sql Server) and b) add the code from your Delphi app that you have at the moment, including the SQL statement(s) it executes.  Without those, I wouldn't be surprised if readers vote to close your q as too broad, which would be a shame because what you would like sounds pretty straightforward, but to get there, we need to know where you're starting from.

Comment: You could just perform 1 SQL statement that returns all records, sorted by CLOSED. Or, you have the 1 button check if the results of the first query are empty, and if so then perform the second query immediately.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you want is to create a SQL statement in your Delphi app and
send it to the server.  If I'm understanding your requirement correctly, only one SQL statement is necessary, even though there are two cases to consider; a) all clients are close and b) some are not.  However, when you construct SQL in a Delphi app, you need to
be aware of the risk of `Sql Injection` - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

A better way would be to define a `Stored Procedure` on your server to retrieve
the data rows you want.  For instance in MS Sql Server, you could create a
`Stored Procedure` like this

```
create procedure GetClients as
  if (select count(*) from Clients where Closed is Null) > 0
    select * from Clients where Closed is Null
  else
    select * from Clients
```

Basically, the `if ...` condition asks is there are any rows where Closed id Null.  If there are, the first `select ...` statement returns them; if there aren't, all the rows are returned.

You can execute it from a Delphi app like this

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOStoredProc1: TADOStoredProc;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoStoredProc1.ProcedureName := 'GetClients;1';
  AdoStoredProc1.Open;
end;
```

(Btw, for this to work, you need to have set up a suitable ConnectionString for AdoStoredProc1 in the Object Inspector.

Notice that this sample app doesn't construct **any** SQL in the Delphi app, so there is no risk of `Sql Injection`.

You didn't say what data type your Closed column is.  For testing, I've assumed
that it's an integer column, but any other type should work.

The above app is deliberately minimalist, basically to illustrate that you can do things like this in server-side code.  In practice, you might what to parameterize the `Stored Proc` so that you can restrict the results based on other Column values.

Comment: I would not use `select count(*) ...` in MSSQL. It has to count all matching records, which is overkill just to find out if something exists. I like to use `select top (1) 1 ...` instead, as it stops searching as soon as the first record is found. If the result set is empty, no records were found, otherwise at least one exists. Much less overhead.

Comment: You have understood my question correctly. Many thanks.  SQL Injection however, If I understand it correctly, will not be an issue for me.  This is an in-house only application and has no access to the outside world therefore it should not be an issue. As mentioned in my ooriginal post, I'm a SQL Newbie so I have a bit of reading to do regarding SQL and stored procedures.

Comment: I want to post some code on here but I don't know if I can do that by just copying and pasting or do I need to use some sort of formatting tags.

Comment: @JerryMallett:  It's easy enough:  Edit your q, paste the code into it and then press Ctrl-K - that formats it as a code block.

Comment: @Remy: I always use IF EXISTS... to me it makes the code easier to read as well, because TOP 1 will return a value from the database that the query does not care about.  But another maintainer in the future, or even myself after I've slept, may not know that and wonder what is being done with the value being retrieved.

Comment: @JonRobertson: you still need a result set from a query in order to use `IF EXISTS`, so it still makes sense to have the query return as little data as possible to satisfy the `IF`. Definately not `count()` for that purpose.  Also, `IF EXISTS` can't be used as the result of a query, only in SQL scripts, like inside of stored procedures. Usually code needs to act on the result of a query, and you can't use `IF EXISTS` for that, but you can use a NULL/EOF check on a `TOP 1` result set. That is what my code usually does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "IF EXISTS can't be used as the result ..."  Not "as" maybe, but what about IF EXISTS() Select 1 else Select -1?

Comment: @MartynA: Maybe, but the query passed to `EXISTS` still needs to return *something* from the server for `EXISTS` to check. Use whatever you want, I like using `SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM ... WHERE ...`, I don't know anything else that uses fewer resources than that.

Comment: @Remy: Of course.  I didn't mean to use EXISTS and COUNT.  I usually do IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...).  EXISTS can also be used in the WHERE clause or a JOIN.  I just won't use TOP 1 if I didn't actually want any data that the TOP would return.  And your solution was already a stored procedure.  :)

Comment: Not important enough for me to go testing, but I thought IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TCustomer WHERE ZipCode = 12345) would be more efficient than IF (SELECT TOP 1 CustID WHERE ZipCode = 12345).  The first version does not return any data from the table, which is fine as the data isn't needed for the evaluation.  The query engine can stop as soon as it locates one match, without retrieving or returning any of the data.

Comment: @JonRobertson I use `IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM ... WHERE ...)`. Maybe the `TOP` is redundant or not. I don't want the server returning a 1 for each matching record, so I tell it to stop after the first record. Doesn't hurt to be explicit.

Comment: My understanding is that the benefit if IF EXISTS is that the query engine will stop once it finds a single match (because multiple matches do not matter).